# Compute the difference in days between the max and the min of a date type column

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, datediff

My table loaded in PySpark has a column "Date" with the following type of data:

| Date | Open | High | Low | Close | Volume | Adj Close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/2012 | 59.97 | 61.06 | 59.87 | 60.33 | 12668800 | 52.61923 |
| 1/4/2012 | 60.21 | 60.35 | 59.47 | 59.71 | 9593300 | 52.07848 |
| 1/5/2012 | 59.35 | 59.62 | 58.37 | 59.42 | 12768200 | 51.82554 |
| 1/6/2012 | 59.42 | 59.45 | 58.87 | 59 | 8069400 | 51.45922 |

How do I calculate the difference, in days, between the max and the min of the column (so in the example above, I need the difference in day between 1/6/2012 and 1/3/2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([('2012-01-03',),('2013-02-03',),('2011-11-29',)], ['Date']).select(F.col('Date').cast('date'))
df.show()
# +----------+
# |      Date|
# +----------+
# |2012-01-03|
# |2013-02-03|
# |2011-11-29|
# +----------+
```

This will create a new dataframe containing the difference in days:

```py
df_diff = df.groupBy().agg(F.datediff(F.max('Date'), F.min('Date')).alias('diff'))

df_diff.show()
# +----+
# |diff|
# +----+
# | 432|
# +----+

# If you need the difference in a variable:
v = df_diff.head().diff
print(v)
# 432
```

And this will add a new column to your existing df:

```py
df = df.withColumn('diff', F.expr('datediff(max(Date) over(), min(Date) over())'))

df.show()
# +----------+----+
# |      Date|diff|
# +----------+----+
# |2012-01-03| 432|
# |2013-02-03| 432|
# |2011-11-29| 432|
# +----------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your dataframe `df` has only the column `Date` in date format, you can do the following:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

(df.withColumn('Max_Date', F.max(F.col('Date')))
   .withColumn('Min_Date', F.min(F.col('Date')))
   .withColumn('Diff_days', F.datediff(F.col('Max_Date'), F.col('Min_Date')))
   .drop('Date').dropDuplicates())
```

In this link you can find more examples about sql functions for pyspark:
https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-functions/

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to work. I assume it is because Date is not the only column in my table

Comment: Please provide the full structure of your dataset in order to receive the proper answer

Comment: Done. My apologies I did not know how to upload table in markdown before

Comment: This doesn't work, because `min` and `max` are aggregate functions, but here they are used without `groupBy` or window partition. This way those functions will not work.